# One-dimensional and two-dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c

There is an array, you need to divide each element of this array by the product of the last digits of the previous and subsequent element.

**Full text of the task:** Fill in a one-dimensional array of 20 elements from a file input.txt and display it on the screen. Change the elements of the array by dividing each element of the array by the product of the last digits of the previous and next element. Print the modified array to the screen on a new line.

How can this be done? I have such a code, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20
int main(void) {
    FILE *output;
    int i, array[N], pred, posl, proizv;
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w+r");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = -100 + rand() % (100 + 100 + 1);
        fprintf(output, "%d ", array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(output, "%d ", &array[i]);
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    fclose(output);
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
        pred = array[i - 1] % 10;
        posl = array[i + 1] % 10;
        proizv = pred * posl;
        printf("%d *%d =%d\n", pred, posl, proizv);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

How can I rewrite it so that I can then output the already modified array to a file?

I have a few more tasks that need to be solved. I will supplement the question as soon as we deal with the first one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The task says "product", I mistakenly wrote about summation.

Comment: @dratenik, will you help me?

Comment: @ДмитрийБлагодер we'd like to help you, but there is not enough information in your question. Read the first comment, especially the [mcve] link.

Comment: If you have other tasks to solve, please don't supplement the question - ask a new question.

Comment: I'll be happy to answer your question, but you have to ask an answerable question for that. The advice linked above is meant to help you do that. "it doesn't work" is not very answerable. What's wrong with it? What are the symptoms of it not working?

Comment: What is the output supposed to be, and what are you getting? Note that the problems states "20 elements" but you are using 5. You haven't read the problem statement very carefully yourself: you are first supposed to output the array to the screen, and again after modifying it, but you have written the divisor as new data to the file. Another thing, is that you are using *already modified* elements to modify the next element.

Comment: By saying "does not work" I mean that the code runs without errors, and that's it. I know (by setting breakpoints) that the code encounters an error just in the for loop, in which it performs actions with array elements. The compiler does not issue errors, but simply "stops executing the program". Yes, I count 5 elements, just to understand whether it works or not. If it works correctly on 5 elements, it will work on 20.

Comment: You get no visible output because there is no `printf` anywhere in the code. BTW are you dividing by 0? If any of the elements you enter is 0 then you will. Please show the input, the expected output and the acual output (after you *do* output the array content).

Comment: To summarise: 1) you aren't outputting anything to the screen, 2) you might be getting 'divide by zero' error (you don't show the *exact* full error message), 3) you are writing data to the input file, 4) you will be modifying an element based on already modified data, you might need to build another array of the result.

Comment: I rewrote the code. It is written in the comments that another array is needed to output the final values. Yes, I need it, I agree. Can I start writing values to it in the same loop where I found 'proizv'? I really didn't understand where to start. Regarding division by 0 - in this problem we were allowed to divide by 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = fopen("output.txt", "w+r");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    array[i] = -100 + rand() % (100 + 100 + 1);
    fprintf(output, "%d ", array[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    fscanf(output, "%d ", &array[i]);
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

One, you don't check either the `fopen()` nor the `fscanf()` for success. Either might fail...

...and the `fscanf()` most certainly *did* fail, because you're still pointing at the *end* of `output` after writing all those values. Try adding `rewind( output )` between the two loops.

> I have a few more tasks that need to be solved. I will supplement the question as soon as we deal with the first one.

Don't. One question per post, please. If you have new questions after this one is resolved, please make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the code should work something like this. Yes, I know about the lack of checking when opening a file for reading, I know about division by 0, but this is a little secondary.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20
int main(void) {
    FILE *output;
    int i, array[N], pred, posl, proizv[N], array2[N];
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w+r");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = -100 + rand() % (100 + 100 + 1);
        fprintf(output, "%d ", array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(output, "%d ", &array[i]);
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    fclose(output);
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
        pred = array[i - 1] % 10;
        posl = array[i + 1] % 10;
        proizv[i] = pred * posl;
        printf("%d *%d =%d\n", pred, posl, proizv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
        array2[i] = array[i] / proizv[i];
        printf("%d ", array2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```